# How do I get the current APEX file name?

Tags: apex, files

Is there something in APEX like `__file__` (Python) or `__FILE__` (PHP and C++)?
Or even something like this in Java:

```
String path = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I think you're describing is a feature of languages called *reflection* or *introspection*.

Apex does not really have either of those. The closest thing we have is the `Type` class, which we can use to dynamically instantiate objects.

```java
// Type.forName() allows us to use a string to determine which class to instantiate
// It returns an Object though, so this isn't of much use beyond using it for things that
//   extend other classes or implement interfaces.
// Objects need to be cast to another type to really be of any use, and the typecast can't
//   be dynamic (the type needs to be known at compile-time)
MyClass mcInstance = (MyClass)Type.forName('MyClass').newInstance();
```

If you want/need the name of a class *inside of that class*, then I think the best we can do is something like this

```java
public class MyClass{
    // "final" makes the variable a constant (write once)
    public final className;

    public MyClass(){
        // <class name>.class gets you an instance of System.Type
        // Basically, it's the statically compilable version of Type.forName().newInstance()
        // System.Type has a getName() method which returns the name of the type
        this.className = MyClass.class.getName();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've never heard anyone refer to __ FILE __ as inflection. It's just a useful global that I hoped would be there. Maybe the terminology has to do with compiled vs. interpreted languages?
I'm familiar with the Java way and I'm not shocked APEX falls short.
I just want the file name to be determined dynamically so I can pre-pend it to USER_DEBUG messages. At the moment all I see is a line number which isn't much help unless I know the file.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I'm following you question (getting a file name vs. getting the Apex class name), but I've used this in the past and seems to faithfully get the current Apex class name:

```
String className = String.valueOf(this).substring(0,String.valueOf(this).indexOf(':'));
```

Comment: That might not work in pure static contexts, but I guess that's fine for classes that you instantiate, which is most anything aside from Aura/Rest/etc.

Comment: Yes, I just ran into an issue with this for static methods.